# PHP search result page into RSS feed

Tags: php, google-apps-script, rss

I am trying to convert the search results page of the following website into an RSS feed by using feed43.com or Google Apps Script:

https://www.zvg-portal.de/index.php?button=Termine%20suchen&land_abk=by

If I click on search (Suchen), I am forwarded to https://www.zvg-portal.de/index.php?button=Suchen but I can access this search result page neither with feed43.com nor with Google Apps Script. Is there a way to access all search results automatically?

Answer (score 0):

you will have to send a POST request to that page. This basically means, that all the data you filled out in the search form is not transported to the search result page via the URL. therefore, if you copy the URL and paste it anywhere else, all information on what you were actually searching has been lost.

Check if the two tools you mentioned also support POST (instead of GET). if so, you can use chromes or firefox web developer tools (network tab) to show the values that were submitted to the search page and copy them there.

Comment: Thanks Matthias, I cannot identify a POST request using Chrome's network tab. Are you sure this website uses POST requests? If so, how would it look like?